# Conflicting class name in jars?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, maximo, bootclasspath

This might sound stupid but is it possible to access classes with same name in 2 jars based on some condition.

My problem is i want to make a standalone java program where in i can connect to my old and new maximo systems through RMI

i am able to access both systems independently but for data migration i need to access both in same class.
Biggest problem is both old and new jar files have same name

Is there any way i can refer to 1st jar in one method and second one in other method?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post some details about your actual problem? The community might be able to come up with a different solution which is more maintainable than duplicate class names.

Comment: A little more details

Comment: A little more details about problem:

we are migrating from 5.2 maximo system to 7.5
both version have same class name psdi.util.MXSession in both systems

Now i want to make connections to both systems in one class but how do i ensure old psdi.util.MXSession is called in method connecting to old system and new psdi.util.MXSession is called in method to connect to new system.

I hope problem statement is clear
Thanks

Comment: Below is the link that helped me for dynamic class loading http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-classloader-Handling

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom class loader. 
here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc5.html) for details. 
just to quote your issue it says

> ... In fact, these applets can contain classes of the same name -- these classes are treated as distinct types by the Java Virtual Machine.